# How to exclude null properties in json using groovy

Tags: json, groovy, null

Using JSONOutput.toJSON to convert objects to json representation in groovy, is there a way to exclude null values to compact the JSON ?

Understand it can be done using jackson, but currently using groovy JSonOutput.

Current Implementation :
**Java Domain**

```
class User {

String firstName;
String lastName;

}
```

**Groovy Script**

```
def user = new User()
user.firstName="abc"

def mapUser = ["userkey",user]

JsonOutput.toJson(mapUser)
```

**Actual Output**

```
{"userkey":{"firstName":abc,"lastName":null}}
```

**Expected Output**

```
{"userkey":{"firstName":abc}}
```

Comment: How are you using it right now?

Comment: Why not use JsonBuilder which uses JsonOutput but gives you more options...

Comment: Provide any sample code.

Comment: @dmahapatro Added code snippet and current implementation. I will give JsonBuilder a try tim_yates

Answer (score 1):

You also could use `JsonGenerator`, but it appeared since 2.5.0:

```
def user = new User()
user.firstName="abc"

def mapUser = ["userkey",user]

def generator = new JsonGenerator.Options()
      .excludeNulls()
      .build()

generator.toJson(mapUser)
```

and you'll get wat you want

Answer (score 0):

You could manually create a map from the objects' properties and serialize that:

```
def "exclude null values"() {
    given:
    def user = new User(firstName: 'abc')
    def mapUser = [ "userkey":
            user.properties
                .findAll { it.key != 'class' && it.value }
    ]

    expect:
    JsonOutput.toJson(mapUser) == /{"userkey":{"firstName":"abc"}}/
}
```

(spock test)